# next/previous like buttons as in mail application in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I am creating a mail like scenario where a user has a next and previous button by which he can move to the next or previous item using iphone. I am able to achieve this but the next item is displayed over the current displaying item there by making the UI look disgusting i.e. the current item still remains in the view.

Is there any way I can create a completely new view or reuse the current view so that the views don't overlap.

What i had planned was to remove all my UI objects when the user clicks next/previous and show them again with the new item. Does this create a new view all-together. Is this the correct solution?

This is the image when i first select a row in table view and show its details : 
[image: This is the image when i first select a row in table view and show its details :]

This is the image when i click the next button on top right corner
[image: This is the image when i click the next button on top right corner]

This is what is happening

[image: A new view is created]

Comment: perhaps a picture would help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as my thought, i think you are creating new views for every navigation. Why don't you just create a global one and load contents in to the same view every time.